# Java path variable doesnt work

Tags: java

I am trying to set up the jdk on my new laptop and am running into a problem. Typing javac gives me 
    `javac` is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

I have set `java_home` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66` and have added `%java_home%\bin\` to the path variable. However, this still does not work. I checked other questions on stack overflow but found nothing. Please help.

Comment: I think it should be `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` should have `bin` location.

Comment: 1) You started a new console (or whatever) after setting the PATH? 2) Confirmed JAVA_HOME is set as you expect? 3) 32/64 bit issues?

Comment: What do you mean by `bin` location? I have `%java_home%\bin`

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between "Program Files" in your `java_home`, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66`?

Comment: Sorry. There is in the `JAVA_HOME` but I wrote it wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following things :

- When you open the environment variable settings, you will find two blocks - one is 'User Variables for Administrator' and the other is  'System variables'. Make sure you are setting the path in the 'System variables' section
- Try putting a hard-coded path in the PATH variable. I have mine as follows :

  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;